# LINQ searching a List that contains a Class with objects

Tags: c#, list, linq, class, search

I'm new at C#, I know how to do a LINQ search to a List with *one* field/type, but not with *many* types of an object. I created a List

```
List<Reader> results = new List<Reader>();
```

That contain this class:

```
public class Reader
{

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }

    public Reader(int id, string name, string course, int grade)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Course = course;
        Grade = grade;
    }
}
```

I want to search it with LINQ and match the `ID` and `Name` of a user that entered the site.
If this two fields are the same I want to take from the List the users `Course` and `Grade`.

Any suggestion how to do it ?

Comment: Read about LINQ `Where` and `Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's assume that you have two variables that hold the values introduced by the user. Those variables are userName of type string and id of type integer. If you just want a variable that holds the course and the Grade you could select a new anonymous type and do the query like this:

```cs
var values= results
   .Where(item => item.ID == userID && item.Name == userName)
   .Select(item => new { Course = item.Course, Grade = item.Grade });
```

then you could use the values like:

```cs
values.Grades

values.Course
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple `Where` for *condition(s)* and `Select` for *representation* should do:

```
 List<Reader> results = ...

 var data = results
   .Where(item => item.ID == userID && item.Name == userName)
// .OrderBy(item => item.Course) // uncomment if you want to order by course
   .Select(item => $"Course: {item.Course} Grade: {item.Grade}");

 foreach (var record in data)
   Console.WriteLine(record);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Selecteduser = results.Where(x => x.Name == selectedname && x.ID == ID).ToList();
if (Selecteduser.Count != 0)
{
    //found match ..(Selecteduser[0])
    string selectedcourse = Selecteduser[0].Course;
    int selectedgrade = Selecteduser[0].Grade;
}
else
{
   //coudlnt find match
}
```